# Giving non-admin users permissions ( to update, to access new wifi, but block DVD writing) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: permissions

Is there a way I can give a non sudoer the permissions necessary for them to update the system through Update Manager? I don't want the user to be able to `apt-get install` whatever like however, just updates.

EDIT: I think something like

```
%someUser ALL=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get update,/usr/bin/apt-get 
upgrade
```

added to the `sudoers` file via `visudo` may work? I would be grateful if someone could confirm as I have no experience of editing this.

For the second part of my question I would like to know how to give the non-admin user privileges to join a WiFi network previously not joined, i.e. say at a hotel or cafe (This is distinct from just ticking the `available for all` box in edit connections for a previously established connection, I mean a genuinely new connection).

Finally I want to remove the privileges for the user to burn to DVD (or CD) but still be able to read DVDs if possible (is this done by restricting permissions to `cdrecord` or would the user still be able to right-click an ISO and `write-to-disc`?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between updates or installing new packages. You need full access to `/` do both. The only way to allow regular users to update would effectively be to make the entire filesystem writeable by everyone, at which point you start wondering why don't you just set every user's id to 0.

I think you want something like `sudo` that, I think, lets you give users permissions to execute specific commands as root.

Comment: OK, but if I find some way to give this user Update ability via `sudo` (I guess by editing the `sudoers` file with `visudo` somehow) I'll have allowed the user to also use this `sudo` privilege to install new packages too?

Comment: I don't know `sudo` personally, I suppose that you can *restrict* what exactly is the user able to run. I just don't know if you can restrict it to updates (unless there's a specific command for updates, instead of just an argument to `apt-get`).

Comment: You can create a shell script executable as root for your users, which contains the "apt-get upgrade -y" command itself. Then you don't allow "apt-get install xxx" but just "apt-get upgrade -y", which does not need any other parameters. This comment is made without worring about security concern ;)

Comment: thanks, I think it may be possible with the command I now added to the OP (not 100% sure though as no experience myself, hopefully someone will be along to confirm). I also added two more parts to my question, that I'd also like to know and suspect may be doable along the same lines of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a daemon process which is run as root. The process runs certain commands you write to a specific file with root permission. A command white list would decide if the given command is run or ignored. With this you effectively create a selective `sudo` command.

**Note however that its not easy to write such a daemon securely.**

Comment: You only want demons on FreeBSD systems, not Ubuntu systems. =)

Comment: @Batman. Ha until now my brain always translated deamon into demon. But of course your right.